# How to properly clean up ViewBindings in RecyclerView adapters?

Tags: android

When using ViewBindings it's very clear in the documentation that you need to clean the binding up when the fragment/activity is being destroyed, otherwise you'd create a memory leak.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    _binding = null

    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

I want to use ViewBindings in my RecyclerView and I see all sorts of guides out there on how to do it, but none of them clean the binding up?

Won't that cause a memory leak?

How do we properly clean them up? Theres no appropriate callback to wipe them all out?

E.g Making them in an adapter

```
return when (viewType) {
      R.layout.message_summary -> {
            val binding = MessageSummaryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            MessageListViewHolderType.Summary(binding)
  }

...

sealed class MessageListViewHolderType(open val binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
      class Summary(
              override val binding: MessageSummaryBinding
      ) : MessageListViewHolderType(binding) {
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps is the only way is add `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener` for `RecyclerView` when you open a binding. And when `onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?)` for `RecyclerView` occurs, perform a cleanup:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    parent.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object: View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {}
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
            v?.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
            binding = null
        }
    })
    binding = ViewHolderViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
// ...
```